# How to draw connecting line(s) between text box label and data point on ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to draw connecting line(s) between text box label (for example the Journal H text box on my below plot) and the corresponding data points but couldn't figure out a way to do this on R apart from getting it done on PowerPoint/Illustrator. My image looks like this[image: My R plot]

Here's how my input data looks like:

```
Journal Year Impact_Factor
1  Journal A 2010          1.91
2  Journal B 2010          9.18
3  Journal C 2012          1.65
4  Journal D 2012          2.40
5  Journal E 2012          3.68
6  Journal B 2013          9.18
7  Journal F 2013          0.79
8  Journal G 2014          1.99
9  Journal H 2016         15.54
10 Journal I 2017          3.82
11 Journal H 2017         15.54
12 Journal B 2019          9.18
13 Journal J 2019          6.78
14 Journal K 2019          3.22
15 Journal L 2020          4.26
16 Journal M 2020         11.08
17 Journal N 2021          4.62
```

and below is the R code that I used:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(RColorBrewer)
nb.cols <- 16
mycolors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Set2"))(nb.cols)
df <- read.csv("Test_publications_list.csv", header=TRUE)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=Impact_Factor, color=Journal)) + 
  geom_point(color= "black", shape= 21, size= 5, stroke= 1, aes(fill = Journal)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors) + 
  theme_gdocs() + 
  geom_label(aes(x = 2017, y = 14, label = "Journal H", fontface= 2), color = "black", fill= NA) + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm")) + 
  ggtitle("Summary plot showing my publications\n in academic journals") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color= "black", size = 10, face = "bold"))
```

I would appreciate it very much if anyone could let me know a convenient way to add the connecting lines on this R plot

Comment: I'd suggest using something like `ggrepel::geom_label_repel`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a suggestion, letting `ggrepel` handle how far to push away.

```r
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=Impact_Factor, color=Journal)) + 
  geom_point(color= "black", shape= 21, size= 5, stroke= 1, aes(fill = Journal)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors) + 
  # theme_gdocs() +  # I don't have ggthemes installed
  geom_label_repel(
    aes(label = Journal),
    data = ~ subset(., Journal == "Journal H" & Year == 2017),
    color = "black", fill= NA, box.padding = 1.5
  ) + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm")) + 
  ggtitle("Summary plot showing my publications\n in academic journals") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color= "black", size = 10, face = "bold"))
```

[image: ggplot2 with label and line to point]

I shifted away from forcing the location (in your code) to allowing it to use the raw data, and shift the label away from the point. My use of `data = ~ subset( )` uses the `rlang`-style tilde-function and base R's `subset`, the `.` in the subset call is the data effective at that time. You can also use `dplyr::filter` if you've already loaded `dplyr` and prefer it. You can also specify `data=df[...]` directly if you prefer, though I often find some dplyr-pipe before the first call to `ggplot(.)`, in which case the original `df` might not be what the data looks like to `ggplot2`. The use of `data=~subset(...)` makes that transparent/consistent.

Note: `ggrepel` uses stochastic processes to *optimize* repelling texts/labels. This means that if you have multiple labels, they may shift from plot-to-plot. There are numerous "controls" you can use, such as some ability to encourage a direction (left/right).

I think the power of using `ggrepel` is that you no longer need to think about where to place things. Without it, all you need is slightly-different data and your hard-coded label locations may all need to change.

---

Alternative, drawing multiple lines between the dots and the one label:

We'll first generate a frame for just the labels:

```r
lbls <- data.frame(Journal = "Journal H", xend = 2017, yend = 14)
merge(lbls, df, by = "Journal")
#     Journal xend yend Year Impact_Factor
# 1 Journal H 2017   14 2017         15.54
# 2 Journal H 2017   14 2016         15.54
```

From here, we use `geom_segment` and an adjusted `geom_label`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=Impact_Factor, color=Journal)) + 
  geom_point(color= "black", shape= 21, size= 5, stroke= 1, aes(fill = Journal)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors) +
  # theme_gdocs() + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend),
               data = merge(lbls, df, by = "Journal")) +
  geom_label(aes(x = xend, y = yend, label = Journal),
             data = lbls, color = "black", fontface = 2, fill = NA) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm")) + 
  ggtitle("Summary plot showing my publications\n in academic journals") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color= "black", size = 10, face = "bold"))
```

[image: ggplot with two line segments, but misplaced]

As you can see, the placement of the lines is to the label center, based on the default offsets for the label box. We can adjust that. Also, there is an additional legend we need to remove, so we'll add a `scale_*`.

```r
lbls2 <- data.frame(Journal = "Journal H", xend = 2017, yend = 14, hjust = 0, vjust = 1)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=Impact_Factor, color=Journal)) + 
  geom_point(color= "black", shape= 21, size= 5, stroke= 1, aes(fill = Journal)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors) + 
  # theme_gdocs() + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend),
               data = merge(lbls, df, by = "Journal")) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  geom_label(aes(x = xend, y = yend, label = Journal, hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust),
             data = lbls2, color = "black", fontface = 2, fill = NA) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm")) + 
  ggtitle("Summary plot showing my publications\n in academic journals") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color= "black", size = 10, face = "bold"))
```

Which now gives us

[image: ggplot, lines shifted, extra legend removed]

You might need to tweak things a bit more. The biggest takeaways I want you to consider with *this* approach:

- instead of hard-coding the `x=` and `y=` as you had, use frames, it is much more extensible;
- `geom_segment` lets us add individual line segments from points "A" to points "B" (where "B" is unchanging for a particular journal in this case, but that's just a convenience);
- using the frame concept, make it easy to merge with the original data in order to fill the `x=` and `y=` of each segment (tying to the `xend=` and `yend=` that we use for the label placement; and
- any other per-journal customization can be addressed in the `lbls` frame.

Comment: Thanks but I had abandoned the use of ggrepel just cos' I couldn't figure a way to draw 2 lines for the same data point. For example, your code managed to draw only one line instead of two to the corresponding two data points. When I had tried running ggrepel prior to posting this question. I was getting duplicate occurrences of "Journal H" labels. Any idea how to avoid duplication of labels but at the same time retaining multiple connecting lines to the corresponding data points?

Comment: My code *"only managed to draw one line"* because your question specifically and clearly only included `(x = 2017, y = 14, label = "Journal H", fontface= 2)`. If you want more than one label, one line, then you need to be explicit about it. If you've tried `ggrepel` and are having difficulties, perhaps you should ask about it. Regardless, your question asks and demonstrates how to connect one point with one label. If you need more, please be more clear.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think my question made it clear- see for example, my very first line- "I would like to draw connecting line(s) between text box label (for example the Journal H text box on my below plot) and the corresponding data points" Since I mentioned 'data points', I thought I had made this requirement clear. Sorry in case it wasn't. I appreciate you taking your time out to post your suggestions.

Comment: Are you saying that you want one label and lines from it pointing to all "H" points? (Occasionally, questions on SO will "photoshop" an image to show what they mean. My apologies if I'm missing something.)

Comment: BTW, I am rereading your question and see my misinterpretation, thanks for the patience and clarification.

Comment: @RodriguezJMathew, see my alternative solution, it might be closer to what you want/need.

Comment: Many thanks @r2evans for your very clear explanations and the alternative solution- much appreciated! Yes, this is very nearly the solution that I was looking for and I must say that you're a great teacher.